# Comparing timestamp in hadoop hdfs

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I'm very new to `hadoop` and all and i have a question on hand. Is there a way to do a comparison of the timestamp between two files in the HDFS?

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [FileSystem.getFileStatus(Path)](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.html#getFileStatus%28org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path%29) method to get a [FileStatus](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileStatus.html) object back, from which you can acquire the file's modified time via [FileStaus.getModifiedTime()](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileStatus.html#getModificationTime%28%29) method

```
FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);
long ts1 = fs.getFileStatus(new Path("/path/to/file1")).getModifiedTime();
long ts2 = fs.getFileStatus(new Path("/path/to/file2")).getModifiedTime();
```